# How to set a matrix as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, function, matrix, parameters

I have an matris that the user will define it's size and it's elemant's value, i want to send it into a function from main as parameter or someway else, tried to use pointer for it but couldn't be successful, defining it as global is not a solution because the value i will give to matris' size is not set until the user enters. A matris can't be a functions parameter as well, so I'm stuck. Anyone can help me to send that matris to the function. - sorry for long question..

```
    int main(){
int matris [k][k];

for(i=0 ; i<k ; i++){
for(t=0 ; t<k ; t++){
cin<<matris[i][t];
}
}
func(a,b,c,x);

}

func(int a, int b, int c, x){
//some stuff
}
```

That's in sum how the code looks like, i know using'x' like that is impossible, i am kinda trying to change the x with the matris value, but we are unable to set a matris as a parameter.

Comment: I have a basic example in [Functions in C](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/functions-in-c/), read that first. Not a downvoter BTW, but you should do better...

Comment: @gsamaras ok MASTER (!). I know how functions r working but just missed a small thing and no need to read the WHOLE documentary which contains the things i already know really mostly, so i am just searching for the small thing i have missed, everyone can miss small

Comment: @gsamaras things sometimes and if they read the WHOLE documents about WHOLE subject it would probably be the end of their lives until they do something well in our nowadays world! So please, if u know how the problem can be solved just honor me with your knowledge about that little part of the WHOLE subject please or if u don't know how to fix or don't want to share how to fix just don't say someone to read WHOLE documents PLEASE, thank you! Sorry for rage but this kind of answers make me mad.

Comment: @gsamaras whole text were too long to share so i needed to divide it into 2 parts

Comment: Uhm, sorry for trying to help Taha. Don't worry, though, I won't try to drive you mad again. :)

Comment: @gsamaras i am always open to helps ofcourse and thank you for reading and sparing time to answer my question  but please, as i said, telling someone  who is stuck on a little thing to read the whole documentary is not just likely help, have a nice day, uhm or night idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the matrix as a `vector<vector<int> >`. Try something like this:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void myFunction(const vector<vector<int> >& matrix) {
  // do something w/ matrix passed in...
}

int main() {
  // create a 3x4 matrix initialized to all zero
  const size_t rowCount = 3;
  const size_t colCount = 4;
  vector<vector<int> > matrix(rowCount, vector<int>(colCount, 0));

  // pass matrix to a function
  myFunction(matrix);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer, you can supply data to functions in 1000 different ways but the OP has asked how to do it in a very specific way.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int const k = 2;

void func( int (&m)[k][k] )
{
    //some stuff
    cout << "func!\n";
}

int main()
{
    int matris[k][k];

    for(int i=0 ; i<k ; i++)
    {
        for(int t=0 ; t<k ; t++)
        {
            //cin >> matris[i][t];
        }
    }
    func( matris );   
}
```

Comment: In fact i want the size, so the "k" to be given by the user too

Comment: @TahaSümer: If you want a dynamic size matrix then you'll have to either implement it yourself or use a library such as Boost. A simple bare bones dynamic matrix implementation is given in the [SO documentation of C++ arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays/10246/a-dynamic-size-matrix-using-stdvector-for-storage#t=201608152229489384357). As it happens written by yours truly (well I'd answered this exact question too many times).